# Initial values for non least squares fit in R

Tags: r, ode, model-fitting, initialization

I am doing a model fitting using **minpack.lm** package. The objective function is the residual between my experimental data & my ODE model.

The tricky thing is the initial value for my ODE model. So I use a loop to run randomly initial values and keep the best result which minimizes the objective function. 
The problem is that if the random initial value is bad, my model can't solve the ODE equation, the result I get is either **NAN** or errors such as **the problem not converged** or **number of time steps 1 exceeded maxsteps at t = 0**. So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to stop when the initial value is bad and pass to the next initial value in one loop?
2. Do you have any advice to choose a best initial value than run randomly?

Thanks a lot